# Unwanted extra gap in longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable

I have finally faced a problem when all googling, this forum and any wittiness could not help me out. I have been working in a  `\longtable` environment when in seemingly the most simple table I have ever made an unwanted extra spacing appeared with no visible for me reason. Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{latvian}

\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
 \caption{Virknes slēguma bezdimensionālie lielumi} \\ %fixed
  \hline
   npk & $\omega$ & $i$ & $u_C$ & $u_L$ \\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead

   \multicolumn{5}{c}
    {{\tablename\ \thetable{} (turpināta no iepriekšējas lappuses)}} \\ \\
  \hline
   npk & $\omega$ & $i$ & $u_C$ & $u_L$ \\
 \hline 
 \endhead

 \hline \multicolumn{5}{l}{{Tabulas turpinājums nākamā lappusē}} \\
 \endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot
  %just data
  1  & 1,71 & 0,891 & 0,522 & 1,52 \\
  2  & 1,68 & 0,923 & 0,551 & 1,55 \\
  3  & 1,62 & 0,995 & 0,614 & 1,61 \\
  4  & 1,45 & 1,32 & 0,911 & 1,91 \\
  5  & 1,30 & 1,86 & 1,43 & 2,42 \\
  6  & 1,21 & 2,51 & 2,07 & 3,05 \\
  7 & 1,16 & 3,32 & 2,87 & 3,84 \\
  8  & 1,10 & 4,94 & 4,49 & 5,43 \\
  9  & 1,01 & 12,8 & 12,6 & 12,9 \\
  10 & 0,984 & 12,3 & 12,5 & 12,1 \\
  11 & 0,955 & 8,47 & 8,87 & 8,09 \\
  12  & 0,941 & 6,98 & 7,42 & 6,57 \\
  13  & 0,926 & 5,87 & 6,33 & 5,43 \\
  14  & 1,04 & 9,07 & 8,71 & 9,45 \\
  15  & 0,868 & 3,41 & 3,93 & 2,96 \\
  16  & 0,752 & 1,71 & 2,28 & 1,29 \\
  17  & 0,665 & 1,19 & 1,79 & 0,790 \\
  18  & 0,578 & 0,867 & 1,50 & 0,501 \\
\end{longtable}
```

I need to use Latvian language, I don't think, that it is important, but just prefered to show my problem as it is. Will appreciate any help and advice.

[image: unwanted gap between 4th and 5th column]

Comment: please always post a complete document, if I guess a preamble for your document I get `! Misplaced \noalign.\hline ->\noalign ` from teh missing `\\ ` after `\caption`

Comment: I have fixed the code. Thank you very much, because this was another problem that I was facing, it just did not bothered me, because compiler created a good pdf file anyway.

Comment: The error corrections that tex makes after an error are more or less entirely arbitrary, a pdf file may be made but really it's not worth looking at except for debugging. Certainly on a forum like this, don't describe one problem and post code that generates unrelated errors:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the extra padding, you could use this solution instead which makes use of longtable's caption facilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{latvian}
\begin{document}
      \begin{longtable}{ccccc}
          \caption{Virknes slēguma bezdimensionālie lielumi}\\
          \hline
          npk & $\omega$ & $i$ & $u_C$ & $u_L$\\
          \hline
        \endfirsthead
          \caption[]{(turpināta no iepriekšējas lappuses)}\\ \\
          \hline
          npk & $\omega$ & $i$ & $u_C$ & $u_L$\\
          \hline
        \endhead
          \hline \multicolumn{5}{l}{{Tabulas turpinājums nākamā lappusē}}\\
        \endfoot
          \hline
        \endlastfoot
        %just data
        1  & 1,71 & 0,891 & 0,522 & 1,52 \\
        2  & 1,68 & 0,923 & 0,551 & 1,55 \\
        3  & 1,62 & 0,995 & 0,614 & 1,61 \\
        4  & 1,45 & 1,32 & 0,911 & 1,91 \\
        5  & 1,30 & 1,86 & 1,43 & 2,42 \\
        6  & 1,21 & 2,51 & 2,07 & 3,05 \\
        7 & 1,16 & 3,32 & 2,87 & 3,84 \\
        8  & 1,10 & 4,94 & 4,49 & 5,43 \\
        9  & 1,01 & 12,8 & 12,6 & 12,9 \\
        10 & 0,984 & 12,3 & 12,5 & 12,1 \\
        11 & 0,955 & 8,47 & 8,87 & 8,09 \\
        12  & 0,941 & 6,98 & 7,42 & 6,57 \\
        13  & 0,926 & 5,87 & 6,33 & 5,43 \\
        14  & 1,04 & 9,07 & 8,71 & 9,45 \\
        15  & 0,868 & 3,41 & 3,93 & 2,96 \\
        16  & 0,752 & 1,71 & 2,28 & 1,29 \\
        17  & 0,665 & 1,19 & 1,79 & 0,790 \\
        18  & 0,578 & 0,867 & 1,50 & 0,501 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: png converted from pdf showing solution using longtable's caption handling]

This, by the way, is how longtable tells you to manage a variant caption if you need a different caption on later pages. Passing the empty optional command to \caption will prevent the table being added to the list of tables a second time.

Comment: Does anybody know how to stop the image being that big? I converted the pdf using convert from ImageMagick. (I only just figured out how to do this at all so perhaps not surprising I'm clearly doing something wrong.)

Comment: I edited it in gwenview but that's a pain. Surely there's a more automatic solution?

Comment: +1 for reading the longtable manual, I should try that one day:-)

Answer (score 3):

If I correct for the omitted `\\` after `\caption`. The problem is that LT caption is a `\multicolumn` and if a spanning cell is wider than the natural width of the cells it spans, TeX puts all the space in the final column. If you add extra padding, things work better.

```
      \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{10pt}}ccccc@{}}
```

[image]

Or perhaps better align on the decimal `,`

[image]

```
      \usepackage{dcolumn}
       \newcolumntype{,}{D{,}{{,}}{3.4}}
\begin{document}

      \begin{longtable}{r,,,,}
        \caption{Virknes slēguma bezdimensionālie lielumi}\\
        \hline
        npk & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$u_C$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ $u_L$} \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{5}{c}
        {{\tablename\ \thetable{} (turpināta no iepriekšējas lappuses)}} \\
        \hline
        npk &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$i$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$u_C$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$u_L$}\\
        \hline 
        \endhead

        \hline \multicolumn{5}{l}{{Tabulas turpinājums nākamā lappusē}} \\
        \endfoot

        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        %just data
        1  & 1,71 & 0,891 & 0,522 & 1,52 \\
```

Comment: Thank you. Personally I prefered the first solution, because I have all my other tables in the document with centered cell elements. By the way, I thought of that a problem was with a caption size, I have tried to change it before but it have not worked for me.

Comment: The problem is that your "caption" is not given as a caption, I think. So longtable adjusts for it whereas if it was specified with \caption, it wouldn't have this effect.

Comment: @cfr oops well spotted:-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using the `S` column construction from [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE % comma instead of full stop as decimal separator
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{latvian}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  S[table-format = 2]
  S[table-format = 1.3]
  S[table-format = 2.3]
  S[table-format = 2.3]
  S[table-format = 2.3]
}
  \caption{Virknes slēguma bezdimensionālie lielumi}
  \label{tbl:something}
  \\
    \toprule
     \mc{npk} & \mc{$\omega$} & \mc{$i$} & \mc{$u_C$} & \mc{$u_L$} \\
    \midrule
   \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Virknes slēguma bezdimensionālie lielumi (turpināta no iepriekšējas lappuses)}
  \\
    \toprule
     \mc{npk} & \mc{$\omega$} & \mc{$i$} & \mc{$u_C$} & \mc{$u_L$} \\
    \midrule
   \endhead
    \bottomrule
     \multicolumn{5}{l}{Tabulas turpinājums nākamā lappusē} \\
     \endfoot
    \bottomrule
     \endlastfoot
      1 & 1.71  &  0.891 &  0.522 &  1.52  \\
      2 & 1.68  &  0.923 &  0.551 &  1.55  \\
      3 & 1.62  &  0.995 &  0.614 &  1.61  \\
      4 & 1.45  &  1.32  &  0.911 &  1.91  \\
      5 & 1.30  &  1.86  &  1.43  &  2.42  \\
      6 & 1.21  &  2.51  &  2.07  &  3.05  \\
      7 & 1.16  &  3.32  &  2.87  &  3.84  \\
      8 & 1.10  &  4.94  &  4.49  &  5.43  \\
      9 & 1.01  & 11.8   & 12.6   & 12.9   \\
     10 & 0.984 & 12.3   & 12.5   & 12.1   \\
     11 & 0.955 &  8.47  &  8.87  &  8.09  \\
     12 & 0.941 &  6.98  &  7.42  &  6.57  \\
     13 & 0.926 &  5.87  &  6.33  &  5.43  \\
     14 & 1.04  &  9.07  &  8.71  &  9.45  \\
     15 & 0.868 &  3.41  &  3.93  &  2.96  \\
     16 & 0.752 &  1.71  &  2.28  &  1.29  \\
     17 & 0.665 &  1.19  &  1.79  &  0.790 \\
     18 & 0.578 &  0.867 &  1.50  &  0.501 \\
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note the use of [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to get the correct horizontal lines.

P.S. Complie three times using `xelatex`.

Comment: The reasin I have not used `siuntix` is exactly because I did not know how to change decimal separator to coma, so thank you very much. I would lika to ask, if it is a common thing that columns are aligned to coma. For example, in this particular case it seems to me that columns are better centered, because rows number 9 and 10 look kind of messy. Am I guessing correctly, saying that this kind of alignment used for scientific notation?

Comment: @Max The alignment depends on the context; normally physical quantities (where the unit usually is set globally on top of the column) are aligned at the decimal separator. I know that it looks somewhat messy, but that again, it is much easier to recognize the relative value of the numbers.